# Remove obsolete values from table that is populated with a For Each loop?

Tags: excel, vba

The current code loops through each worksheet that begins with "Rev" and returns a specific cell value, which populates a table on my worksheet "Table".

This works fine. However, if a Rev worksheet is removed, the value in the Table worksheet remains.

With that background info, what is a solution to only keep current Rev worksheet values from populating the table?

```
Sub Rev_loop()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim n As Long

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Rev*" Then
        n = n + 1
        Worksheets("Table").Cells(n).Value = ws.Range("B2").Value

    End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is this code run from?  Do worksheets disappear while it's running?

Comment: I run this function with a form control button. Worksheets do not disappear?

Comment: Then why is it an issue if Rev worksheets disappear?  It sounds like you're removing them during the execution.

Comment: if a Rev worksheet disappears (is deleted).... then then next time I run this function (update table values).... I would like the deleted worksheets' values also removed from the table that this for loop function generates

Comment: If you don't want outdated data, then your best bet is to clear out the persistent values prior to regenerating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the table first. Then iterate through the Worksheets as before.

Something like this:

```
Worksheets("Table").Range("B2:B99").ClearContents
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to clear the table before your next loop, you have to remember the sheet's names somewhere.

By this example you can store the sheet's names and their value together in the first two columns:

```
Sub Rev_loop()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long

    With Worksheets("Table")
        n = 0
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Name Like "Rev*" Then
                n = n + 1
                .Cells(n, 1).Value = ws.Name
                .Cells(n, 2).Value = ws.Range("B2").Value
            End If
        Next ws
    End With
End Sub
```

By this second loop, you compare the stored sheet's names and delete all rows with outdated names:

```
Sub Correct_loop()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim StillValid As Boolean
    Dim n As Long

    With Worksheets("Table")
        For n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            StillValid = False
            For Each ws In Worksheets
                If ws.Name = .Cells(n, 1).Value Then
                    StillValid = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next ws
            If Not StillValid Then .Rows(n).Delete
        Next n
    End With
End Sub
```